# NSInternalInconsistencyException: There can only be one UIApplication instance

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tvos

### Description:

Trying to open a Youtube URL in my application using the `UIApplication` class.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smOp5aK-_h0")!
let app = UIApplication()
if app.canOpenURL(url){
  //Crash here
  app.openURL(url)
}
```

### Question:

Why does my application crash when I attempt to open the url?

### Error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication init],
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'There can only be one
>   UIApplication instance.'

Edit: Does not crash but doesn't open the link:

```
       if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
            print("Can open shared application url.")
            if #available(tvOS 10.0, *) {
                print("tvOS 10.0 detected")
                UIApplication.shared.open(url){res in
                    //res is false... 
                    print("Result..." + String(res))
                }
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can tvOS open https urls? Maybe try using YouTube's URL scheme

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is saying:

> There can only be one UIApplication instance

Means that there is one instance should be called, when working with `UIApplication` it should be `shared` (singleton) instance. As mentioned in [UIApplication's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication):

> The UIApplication class provides a centralized point of control and
>   coordination for apps running in iOS. Every app has exactly one
>   instance of UIApplication (or, very rarely, a subclass of
>   UIApplication). When an app is launched, the system calls the
>   UIApplicationMain(*:*:*:*:) function; among its other tasks, this
>   function creates a **Singleton UIApplication object**. Thereafter **you
>   access the object by calling the shared() class method**.

*shared()*:

> All UIApplication notifications are posted by the app instance
>   returned by shared().

So what do you need to is to change `let app = UIApplication()` to `let app = UIApplication.shared`:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smOp5aK-_h0")!
let app = UIApplication.shared
if app.canOpenURL(url) {
    app.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Or:

```
// for being safe, I suggest also to do "optional-binding" for the url:
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smOp5aK-_h0") {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It doesn't crash anymore, but it doesn't open the url even if "canOpenURL" returned true. Any ideas? I added the completionHandler and it returned "false".

Comment: Glad to help. So, if you added a breakpoint to the line of UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil), will it be reachable?

Comment: @rugdealer Simulator or real device?

Comment: Yup, like I said. I added the completionHandler which returns a Bool. Unsure what it's supposed to mean, but it's false. I'm using a real device.

Comment: @Sulthan Should it be so different if using the simulator or a real device? in fact I'm not familiar with working with tvOS :)

Comment: Really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error says it clearly. You have to use the default application. `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)`